# Azure DevOps dotnet build cannot find restored nuget packages

Tags: azure-devops

I am having a weird problem with Azure DevOps, which is that `dotnet restore` can restore nuget packages successfully but `dotnet build` failed because the packages cannot be found.

Here is the steps in my pipeline, as well as some output from each steps

1. `dotnet restore`

In this step, I specifically set the Destination to `packages` folder in root so that I can verify that packages are actually stored. In addition, since I am using private nuget repo, I specify the NuGet.config file and the credentials.

2. `ls && ls packages`

I would like to make sure packages are restored so I add this step. From the output, I can see that packages from both nuget repo and my private repo are there

3. `dotnet build`

I get error in this step (not always. this step will be succeed occasionally, sometimes after I update some pipeline config). In this step, the error says

`The type or namespace name 'Migrations' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

For this step, I also tried to use PowerShell with command `dotnet build Booking.Server.csproj -c Release --no-restore --source ..\packages` and I got the same error.

===========================================

In addition, I also checked my csproj file that no package is referenced from a local path.

Can anyone please help?

Thank you.

=============================================
**Update yaml file**

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: Booking.Server/NuGet.config
    externalFeedCredentials: 'GitLab Nuget Repository'
    restoreDirectory: packages
    verbosityRestore: Diagnostic

- powershell: |
   ls
   ls packages
   ls packages/booking.shared
   
  displayName: 'Check pakcages'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    projects: Booking.Server
    arguments: '-c Release --no-restore --source ..\packages'
    workingDirectory: Booking.Server
  enabled: false

- powershell: |
   ls
   ls ..
   ls ../packages
   dotnet build Booking.Server.csproj -c Release --no-restore --source ..\packages --verbosity diag
  workingDirectory: Booking.Server
  displayName: Build
```

Comment: Can you provide the yamls/ screenshot of the steps with all config values?

Comment: Hi @Repcak, the yaml has been attached in the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The probable cause of this problem is your path points to the incorrect packages folder, especially the confusion between folders and subfolders. You can refer to [this blog](https://www.codeart.dk/blog/2020/3/packages-restored-but-your-project-is-still-missing-references/).

Comment: Hi @Jane Ma-MSFT, thank you for your suggestion. I think the package folder is correct because the build can be succeed occasionally (1 out of 3) without changing any configuration.

Comment: @Ben Sorry for the late reply. Could you try running you pipeline on your [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) to see if there are the same errors? This can help find the cause of the question.